# python-opencv Extract only black colour sign on the traffic sign

Tags: python-3.x, colors, opencv3.0

I need help to extract black color from an image on white background. For example, this is one of traffic sign image.

[image]

I want to get rid of red color on image and just want to see black color part as like this image

[image]

Please, help me to solve this problem. If you can give code, it will be very helpful.